# Random Number within a range but exclusive (...]

Tags: c

For instance, the following gives you a random number between [0-10].

```
srand(time(NULL));
int r = ( rand() % 10 ) + 1;
```

I want to make it something like `(0-10]`, i.e. excluding zero but including 10. I may use if condition here but I want more neat solution.

Thank you

Comment: No, this does not give you `[0-10]`.

Comment: Your code gives you what you want, a number between 1 and 10 including 1 and 10: http://ideone.com/PiA1Wn

Comment: Note this will generate a non-uniform distribution for typical implementations.